# How do you add auth to the routes provided by eve_swagger?

Tags: eve

I'm using eve_swagger (https://github.com/pyeve/eve-swagger) in a project and it works great for generating swagger docs.  I have a use case where I need to have the default `/api-docs` endpoint that is created as a route in the library require authentication.

When I create my eve app, I set the `auth` param to my auth class, but /api-docs endpoint is created with a blueprint and I'm not sure how I can add auth to this endpoint.  Any ideas?

My eve* deps:

```
eve = "~0.7"
eve_sqlalchemy = "~0.7"
eve_swagger = "^0.0.11"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way, not sure if this is the best/right way though.

I take the eve_swagger blueprint that's provided, and add a before_request with an authorization function.  Something "like" this:

```
import eve_swagger
from flask import current_app as app

def authorize_swagger:
    # my auth logic

eve_swagger.swagger.before_request(authorize_swagger)
app.register_blueprint(eve_swagger.swagger)
```

The result of doing this is now when I call the default `/api-docs` route, my authorization function is called and processed before the request.  This way if my function decides the request is not authorized, it can stop the request.